# About statusBar within application

Tags: ios, statusbar

Sorry, I don't know how to expound this issue!  Looking at the below image
[image]

The front view not show statusBar, but the back view appear within app. Like this, how to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to hide the StatusBar during the Application Launch.
To achieve this you simply have to set a checkbox in your project settings. Click on your Target and click on the checkbox "Hide during Application Launch".
[image]

If you really want to hide the StatusBar for a single view you can use in `viewWillAppear`the following piece of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

And in `viewWillDisappear`simply set the value to NO.

Comment: No,no,the app has been launched. Then the appear is handle the touch event. Thank you all the same.

Comment: I think can't achieve with you provide way.

Comment: What's the problem? I've tested the code and it hides and shows the status bar as expected.

Comment: Your code is correct when app during the launch. My problem is that after app has been launched, app has two views, one hidden statusBar, another show statusBar. How can achieve this?

Comment: whether that app has two windows view or not?

Comment: I don't get it.. You have two ViewControllers, say View1 and View2. If View1 is visible you want to hide the StatusBar? When the user navigates to View2 the StatusBar should be visible again?

Comment: Did you download Google maps from iOS app store? Map view from left to right When you drag button on the bottom right corner, setting view appear. Map view hidden statusBar, setting view show statusBar,can achieve?

Comment: Please sharing, if you have a progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the status bar with:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

You could put that code within the front view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

//...
}
```

And you can show it again with:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];`

Comment: I think, can't achieve with you provide way. May you can write a demo to test it.

Comment: Yes, I did. StatusBar was an application object, so the statusBar show    by [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:Yes/NO] in the final UIViewController's viewDidLoad method. Right?